# AWS is rejecting my credentials when I try to push to S3 from an Ubuntu server instead of my local machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-18.04, aws-cli

I have a client (as in a customer, not a program!) who runs a site powered by S3 and Cloudfront. I developed a data-driven Web interactive (powered by JS, of course) that I regularly update for them since the data updates frequently. I use the public/private key pair they provided me since I do not, quite reasonably, have access to their entire AWS account.

The client would like the ability to update the interactive any time, even if I'm not immediately on call. But it's unrealistic for me to ask them to replicate my local environment through a Docker container or what-have-you -- I'm not even sure they have admin access to their Macs. I do not have a direct contact to their DevOps team that manages the infrastructure. (It's a big company, and my points of contact are not developers.)

My plan was to spin up a small, cheap EC2 instance on *my* AWS account, install the necessarily languages and libraries to replicate what I do from my machine: fetch the new data and process it (in `R` -- the raw files are very large so the interactive cannot fetch them directly), recompile the interactive (in `Node.js`, using Webpack) and push it live or to a staging server (using `awscli`, Amazon's Python client). I already have simple Shell scripts to do all of this in one fell swoop and I've confirmed that the client is able to `ssh` into my small instance using a `.pem` file I provided them and run one or two Shell scripts.

**The problem**: The client's AWS account is rejecting the credentials they provided me when an upload request comes from my tiny Ubuntu 18.04 server instead of my local machine. There are many competing instructions out there for how to install `awscli` on Ubuntu -- aptitude, pip, [direct download from Amazon](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-cliv2-linux.html), etc. I've tried them all, and am currently using this version on the server:

```
$ aws --version
aws-cli/1.18.104 Python/3.6.9 Linux/5.3.0-1030-aws botocore/1.17.27
```

I ran `aws configure` on the server, made absolutely certain I was using the correct key pair, and set it up fine (or so I thought). But when I test it with an innocuous command, I'm told the key is invalid:

```
$ aws s3 ls s3://[client's s3 instance]
An error occurred (InvalidAccessKeyId) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation:
The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.
```

When I run this exact same command on my local machine, a MacBook, using the same credentials, it works just fine. I'm 100% certain I'm using the same key pair -- I checked manually.

So I'm perplexed as to why AWS rejects a request from an Ubuntu server but accepts one from a local machine. I've been through every StackOverflow post and message board I can find, but the diagnosis is usually that the key pair is wrong, which it isn't.

The only thing I can think of is that I'm using a different version of `awscli` locally. On my local machine, I'm still using an older version:

```
 $ aws --version
 aws-cli/1.16.10 Python/2.7.17 Darwin/19.6.0 botocore/1.12.0
```

I'm reluctant to update the cli on my machine in case it breaks there too but can test in a VM. But more to the point, I'm wondering if, under the hood, there's a more fundamental difference been running an `aws` command from a server versus a laptop. It's tricky thing to Google for!

Answer (score 0):

After all that, and checking 100 times, there was one character missing in the credentials on the server. Order is restored in the universe. Thanks!